# Connect laptop's webcam with new Genymotion

Tags: adb, android-emulator, genymotion

I noticed that the new version of Genymotion 3.3.x doesn't have anymore the (very useful) webcam activation feature. As I would just need that and I have no need to use more advanced features, is there a way to attach the webcam to the emulated android device maybe using adb?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The ability to connect a webcam is now a paying feature:

> New “media injection” widget, replacing the old “camera” widget. This
> enables you to feed images, videos and audio files as well as any
> detected camera to the virtual device microphone and cameras. **Only
> available with a paying license.**

https://www.genymotion.com/blog/release-note/genymotion-desktop-3-3-0-beta-1/

Comment: Yup I'm aware of that but I thought that the widget was "just" a gui to simplify some "lower level" functionality which could be achieved otherwise. After all, is the "media injection widget" being available only for a payment, it doesn't exclude that I could be able to let the emulated device see the camera otherwise? Or am I wrong on that? (I'm a bit reluctant to pay because I wouldn't need the whole functionality but just the old camera redirection)

Comment: @rubiker The text clearly states that feeding vide stream into Genymotion is now a paying feature. If the functionality would still be available using a workaround in the free license I assume this would be a bug that would be fixed soon by Genymotion.